# how to get rid of an array inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const addressZip = person.get('addresses').filter((address) => address.get('legacy_id')).filter((newAddress) => (
  getZIPErrors(newAddress.get('zip'))
))
```

when this function is executed it returns me as an 
`[array(0)]` if it has no error 
when it has an error it returns me as an `[array(1)]`.

Instead of returning an array inside an array I just want to return a single array in this way if it has no error `[]` and if it has an error it should be like `['invalid']`

Comment: Generally, you can the get the value at the first index of `myArray` with `myArray[0]`. So, in your case, adding `[0]` after the closing parentheses  would pull `['invalid']` out of `[['invalid']]`

Comment: i don't want the 0 index value as there may be more elements in an array with the errors1st item may have error 2nd may be null and third may have the error again so instead of showing array inside an array it should return inb main array itself  like this ['invalid', null, "invalid"]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a concatAll method within Array constructor, then use it to flatten your result:

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
  return this.reduce((acc, curr) => acc = acc.concat(curr))
}

const addressZip = person
  .get('addresses')
  .filter(address => address.get('legacy_id'))
  .filter(newAddress => getZIPErrors(newAddress.get('zip')))
  .concatAll()
```